# Rank students depending on their class

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I am trying to rank my students depending on their class (exam_place_id) by their points.

This is my database 
[image]

For example student with highest point in exam_place_id 11 will be ranked as 1 
highest point in exam_place_id 12 will be ranked 1 as well

overall ranking is their score in overall

I've done overall ranking by

```
select er.*,
      (@rank := @rank + 1)       as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @point := -1) params

order by point desc;
```

however when I try

```
select er.*,
      (@rank := @rank + 1)       as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @point := -1) params
**group by exam_place_id** 
order by point desc;
```

it does not work.

Note : I also want to update my class_ranking column with the values but my current query does select.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the exam places and use this for the ranking:

```
select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@ep = exam_place_id, @rank + 1,
                    if(@ep := exam_place_id, 1, 1) 
                   )
       ) as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @ep := -1) params
order by exam_place_id,
         point desc;
```

Comment: also how can I update my table with the values I recieve ?

Comment: You can join from the original table to this query.